# <asynchronous suspension> comment when flutter doctor --android-licenses -v

Tags: android, flutter, upgrade, android-sdk-manager

I was happy with flutter development till
I ran **flutter upgrade**.

After this the apps developed failed.

This all with **Windows**

Because the **flutter doctor** and **sdkmanager --update** commands were without effect

I uninstalled all android studio and destroyed the data in android sdk and flutter.

After **reinstallation** beginning with flutter then android studio and then from android studio sdk installation

I have the same
remarks in **flutter doctor -v**
Flutter (**Channel master**, v0.7.6-pre.27 ...
**! Some Android licenses not accepted**

In flutter **doctor --android-licenses -v**
are **remarks**

-

**AndroidWorkflow.runLicenseManager**

(package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_workflow.dart:229:7)

**asynchronous suspension**

-

**Doctor.diagnose**

(package:flutter_tools/src/doctor.dart:137:30)

**asynchronous suspension**

-

**DoctorCommand.runCommand**

(package:flutter_tools/src/commands/doctor.dart:29:39)

**asynchronous suspension**

+

With **administrator rights**

**sdkmanager --update --verbose**

there I read

Warning: File C:\Users\my_account\.android**repositories.cfg** could not be loaded

If I looked in the folder C:\Users\my_account\.android

and **found no file** with the name **repositories.cfg**

Please give me advice how to solve this dilemma.

Erhy

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the absence of android licenses

with the command

**sdkmanager --licenses  --verbose**

in which I was asked for accepting the licenses for each module

I answered all the questions

**Accept? (y/N):**

with

**y**